# How to repeat one scene of Three.js inside an @foreach of database?

Tags: asp.net, three.js, webgl

I'm new using Three.js and I need to repeat the scene according the columns of my databse so I tried to insert the script inside the @foreach but it doesn't work because I only can have 16 webgl renderers.

I'm gonna put the last code I tried to make it work. The import isn't working and i dunno in what other way to do

```
   <!-- Three.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>

    <!-- OrbitControls -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <!-- FBXLoader -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>

    <script>
    var container = document.getElementById('lavador');
    container.id = 'scene';

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true, canvas: container});
    var gl = renderer.getContext('webgl');

    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xeee6d1, 0);
</script>
@foreach (var item in Model.Lavadores)
{
    <script >
        const scene = new THREE.Scene()

        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.5)
        scene.add(ambientLight)
        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        directionalLight.position.set(5, 10, 7.5);
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        var w = container.offsetWidth;
        var h = container.offsetHeight;
        renderer.setSize(w, h);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
        camera.position.set(10, 0, 8);
        camera.rotation.set(0, 1, 0);

        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
        controls.enableDamping = true
        controls.target.set(0, 1, 0)

        const fbxLoader = new THREE.FBXLoader()

        fbxLoader.load(
            'fbx/Paleto.fbx',
            (object) => {
                object.position.set(2, 1, -2);
                object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
                scene.add(object)
            },
            (xhr) => {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate)

            controls.update()

            render()
        }


        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera)
        }

        animate();
    </script>
```

I there's other way to do I woulb be grateful
PD: I cant import in other way, this the only it works for me